# i have a python code to extract features from the tweets. so i have to give my tweets file as the input along with its path. how to do this?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

def main():

```
init_dicts()  #initialize the dictionaries 

trainingFile = open("output.csv",'a')
wr = csv.writer(trainingFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

path_sarcastic = os.path.abspath(in.txt + "C:\Desktop/miniproject/project_test") + "/sarcastic_with_past"
fileListSarcastic = os.listdir(path_sarcastic)
for i in fileListSarcastic:
    list_tweets = []
    features = []
    with open(path_sarcastic+'/'+i) as tweet_file:
        file_reader = csv.DictReader(tweet_file)
        for row in file_reader:
                try:
                    words = preprocess(row['tweet'],stopwords)
                    list_tweets.append(words)
                except:
                    print "problem"
    words = list_tweets[0]
    past = list_tweets[1:]
    features = getFeatureHelper(words , past)
    features.append(1)
    wr.writerow(features)
```

my error is:

> ~/Desktop/miniproject/project_test$ python driver_final.py   File
>   "driver_final.py", line 93
>       path_sarcastic = os.path.abspath(in.txt + "C:\Desktop/miniproject/project_test") + "/sarcastic_with_past"
>                                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

someone please help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is :
this is a wrong way to make absolute path that is why you see this syntax error:

> os.path.abspath(in.txt + "C:\Desktop/miniproject/project_test") +
>   "/sarcastic_with_past"

Here is what you need to do :

**replace :**

```
path_sarcastic = os.path.abspath(in.txt + "C:\Desktop/miniproject/project_test") + "/sarcastic_with_past"
```

**with :**

```
path_sarcastic = os.path.abspath("C:\Desktop/miniproject/project_test"+"/sarcastic_with_past"+"/in.txt")
```